# How do you make a scroll through animation in a listview?

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I have a button below on my listview that allows the user to press it to auto-scroll back to the top of the list. I was wondering if there was a way to make it so that the button can visually scroll back to the top of the list instead of just jumping to the top. My current button code is as follows

```
ImageButton toTop = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.topButton);
    toTop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mListView.setSelection(0);
            mListView.requestFocus(0);
            v.performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.VIRTUAL_KEY);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simple,Android provides method for this..

```
         mListView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
```

Comment: I didnt see your answer till now. This works perfectly so thanks :). Also, i dont have enough rep for my upvote to show publicly.